# Removing filters on on string array in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

if someone would help me, it would be highly appreciated :). 
I've been struggling a bit with the syntax of typescript(beginner here).

I need to refactor this code so that I can get the complete list of serviceBranches. 
Right some filtering and mapping is done and one serviceBranch is being returned from our API.
I've already tried removing some filters but probably not the correct ones. 
Can someone help me in getting all the serviceBranches (so in order words removing the correct filters).

Thank you.

```
public async personNews(serviceBranch?: string[]): Promise<INews> {
    const fetchResult: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[] = await this._get('api/person/news/', newsSchema, true) as IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[];
    const serviceBranches: string[] = (serviceBranch !== undefined ? serviceBranch : fetchResult.filter((entry: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry, index: number, array: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[]): boolean => { 
      return entry.niveauID === NewsLevel.ServiceBranch && array.findIndex((value: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry): boolean => {
        return entry.unitID === value.unitID;
      }) === index;
    }).map((entry: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry): string => {
      return entry.unitID;
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why everything has explicit type?

Is it because `this._get('api/person/news/', newsSchema, true);` returns `any`?

After slight refactoring and removing types it is more clear

```js
public async personNews(serviceBranch?: string[]): Promise<INews> {
  const fetchResult = await this._get('api/person/news/', newsSchema, true);

  let serviceBranches: string[] = [];

  if(serviceBranch) {
    serviceBranches = serviceBranch;
    return;
  }

  serviceBranches = fetchResult.filter((entry, index, array) => { 
    return entry.niveauID === NewsLevel.ServiceBranch
        && array.findIndex(({unitID}) => entry.unitID === unitID) === index;
    }).map(entry => entry.unitID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very dense function that is pretty hard for a human to parse and understand. So lets format it better:

```
public async personNews(serviceBranch?: string[]): Promise<INews> {
  const fetchResult: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[] = (await this._get(
    'api/person/news/',
    newsSchema,
    true,
  )) as IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[]
  const serviceBranches: string[] =
    serviceBranch !== undefined
      ? serviceBranch
      : fetchResult
          .filter(
            (
              entry: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry,
              index: number,
              array: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry[],
            ): boolean => {
              return (
                entry.niveauID === NewsLevel.ServiceBranch &&
                array.findIndex(
                  (value: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry): boolean => {
                    return entry.unitID === value.unitID
                  },
                ) === index
              )
            },
          )
          .map((entry: IPersonNewsFetchResultEntry): string => {
            return entry.unitID
          })
```

Now it's pretty clear that `fetchResult` is first filtered to remove some items, then those items are mapped over to return just their `unitID`.

From your question it's hard to know what logic you want or what your data looks like. However, if you want *all* results, that remove the `filter()` call entirely. If you want to return whole objects instead of just the `unitID`, remove the `map()` call entirely. If you want different filtering logic, change the internal logic of that `filter`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  No, I need those unitIDs.

Comment: .
I forgot to say, I tried removing the filter, but I still get just one unitID. 
Though your reformatting certainly helped!  You were right about the density.

Comment: Use a [debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) to explore this function when it executes, figure out what data is getting turned into what result, and then adjust your logic accordingly. Without know your data and what specifically your goal is with that data, it's hard to avise more.